# Should honesty be mentioned in CV?

Tags: resume

In the CV template I'm using there is a section for me to fill in my strengths. How should I optimize this section? I think that I'm a honest person, and I believe it's a strength, but should I write this down? I'm afraid that it would be... too honest.

Here is my draft:

> #### My strength
>
> Writing and presenting
>   Research ability
>   Productivity enthusiastic
>   Honesty and diligence

Comment: "What's your biggest weakness?" *"Honesty."* "I don't think honesty is a weakness" *"I couldn't care less what you think"* - all over the internet.

Comment: @KateGregory +1 for the sanitized version :)

Comment: To be honest (ha) the whole "strengths" should be discarded. I don't want to read bullet points of words - I want to see your experience. For one thing, none of what you listed is "special" - I'd expect all that from anyone applying to work for me. I want to see where you used those things to effect - world tech manuals, running training sessions, going the extra mile...

Comment: @HorusKol I thought that what you describe should be written in the cover letter; the CV only list your quantifiable achievements. Listing those bullets is my best attempt to quantify my strengths without having to write a whole paragraph.

Comment: No, the cover letter is where you say why you think you should have the job. Your CV is where you list your experience, and your previous roles and responsibilities, and achievements. Your bullet list doesn't quantify anything because you don't provide evidence to back it up

Comment: @HorusKol so do you have any suggestion to list my achievements that is hard to be quantified? I don't think I should attend a writing contest and win a prize just to prove that I'm (acceptably) good at writing (I don't want to bombast in the CV or in this comment)

Comment: If you're (acceptably) good at writing, then the fact that you have written a cover letter and CV is usually enough demonstration. However, did you ever have to write documentation, or communicate via email, or use your writing skill in any way in your previous jobs. Then include how you applied your skill(s) in the paragraph of roles and responsibilities you should have for each previous job.

Comment: If this is a resume for your first job out of school - then describe situations at school/college/uni where those skills applied. The key thing is to *demonstrate* applications of skill, not simply show them in a list. If you can't demonstrate it, don't mention it - it is generally assumed that you have a base level of honesty/diligence/enthusiasm.

Comment: @HorusKol *Then include how you applied your skill(s) in the paragraph of roles and responsibilities you should have for each previous job* - this goes to the cover letter, right? (Presuming that the work requires me to have good writing skills)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44928/discussion-between-horuskol-and-ooker).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I cannot think of any role where honesty and diligence is not *expected* of the candidate. You are not adding any value to your resume by mentioning it. Even a dishonest candidate would describe himself as honest, if asked.

The purpose of your resume is to get you an interview call, and every word in the resume should contribute to it. "Honesty and diligence" is not really serving that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Under the category "My Strengths", it seems that "honesty" does not belong there.

It's more belongs to "Why me?" or "Why to hire me?" session. 
It only essential in a situation like where, There are two candidates with equally qualified  to a position and that one of them is you, so you have to come up with something more competitive than the other.  In a detailed CV it's great to mention that. Your technical skills should directly come under "My Strengths" session.

For a example under strengths, 
"I'm a strong believer with can do attitude. That believe long R&D time is NOT a waste but a real payback to the company.".
So that the company know he/she is well suited for such R&D job. That who knows the nature of R&D business.

On strengths session you can convenience your employer that you are in a strong position and match with the position that they going to hire.

"Honesty" comes after that, in a case they could find two strong well fitting candidates to a one competitive position.

Comment: How likely are they ever to be faced with two candidates, one of whom claims to be honest and the other claims to be dishonest?

Comment: In R&D industry there are none. We recently have a opening and our HR guys have hard time to find a suitable candidate for the position. The reality is position exists without a candidate. Neither we are full qualified candidates for that position.

Comment: @sandun It seems you misunderstood her question. How often did you have two equally qualified candidates, one of whom claimed to be honest and the other claimed to be dishonest?

Comment: @MaskedMan , In a business like R&D not about about  seeking equally qualified. Positions kept open for 6 months sometimes, and that's the nature of R&D industry. Somehow we need to take the right matching candidate with the position. But in other industries like just teaching there could be equally qualified number of candidates who are already qualified for the position. In that case HR will read further your CV. In that case mentioning it over non mentioning it would be an advantage.

Comment: Sound everybody is honest and it's already assumed if that's CV for a top job(that term top job is not much polite either). So mentioning it only be an advantage in that above mentioned scenario.